# Изменение родительского элемента по клику на дочерний js/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть следующая ситуация:

На странице ряд кнопок с выезжающим текстом данной структуры:

`div1.current_color_class_div >  div2 > div3 > button`

Задача, чтобы при клике на кнопку button `div1` менял цвет(то есть, весь блок целиком).

Т.к. js почти не знаю - не могу придумать адекватного решения. На данный момент использую такой `jquery` скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.current_color_class_div').click(function () {
   $(this).toggleClass('add_target_color_class');
   });
 });
```

Но фокусируюсь на `div1`, который не является кнопкой. То есть цвет может меняться без срабатывания кнопки, что безусловно баг.

Есть ли возможность сфокусироваться из кнопки на родителя? Чистый js или `jQuery` - значения не имеет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

клик надо добавить кнопке, а внутри искать ближайшего родителя по имени класса

```
 $("button").click(function(){
      $(this).closest('current_color_class_div').toggleClass('...');
 });
```

селектор `$("button")` тут возможно слишком общий будет, так что либо кнопкам добавить какой-то общий класс, либо сделать селектор `.current_color_class_div button`

Comment: Это в том случаи если current_color_class_div по любому находится выше по иерархии дом (будь он в соседнем элементе или в любом другом месте дом "кроме родительской иерархии" и ...)

Comment: @noname2019 конкретная структура приведена автором в вопросе

Comment: Вопросов нет. Извините за камень в огород))

Comment: @teran, большое спасибо! Данный скрипт решает описанную проблему

Comment: @ptpwork ткните галку ответу тогда